# CA Signed Cert install on another machine CSR

Tags: openssl, certificate, self-signed, ca

I have a CSR generated from another machine and I use that CSR to CA sign using local CA set up. When I have executed

```
    openssl verify /root/tmp/tmp/cacert.pem /root/tmp/servercert105.pem
```

> ```
> /root/tmp/tmp/cacert.pem: C = US, ST = CA, L = orris, O = HOLO, OU = Nt, CN = x.x.x.x, emailAddress = nh@hl.com
> error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
> OK
> /root/tmp/servercert105.pem: C = US, ST = CA, L = Morris, O = CM, OU = 3009, CN = 0000010
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
> ```

```
 openssl verify -CAfile /root/tmp/tmp/cacert.pem /root/tmp/servercert105.pem
```

> /root/tmp/servercert105.pem: OK

and this is root signed and does not have intermediate certs.  Is this expected error when I have tried without -CAfile option?

Answer (score 0):

**YES.**

When you do `openssl verify -CAfile x y` it means:

- verify the (single or first) cert in file y, using the cert(s) in file x as trusted CA cert(s)

Since your servercert105 is signed by(1) your cacert, this succeeds.

(1) Technically a child cert is *signed* by the private key of a parent CA, and *verified* by the cert of that parent CA matching the private key, which parent cert is itself also verified or else explicitly trusted. We usually simplify this by saying the child is signed by the parent cert.

When you do `openssl verify x y` it means:

- first, verify the (single or first) cert in file x, using the system default truststore
- then, verify the (single or first) cert in file y, using the system default truststore

These steps are separate and independent. Apparently your default truststore does not have your cacert installed, so:

- verifying cacert which is selfsigned against the default truststore fails, because it is not in the truststore, thus verify error 18
- verifying servercert105 against the default truststore fails, because its parent is not in the truststore, thus verify error 20